# Logstash output to Elasticsearch SSL certificate

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, ssl, certificate, logstash

I have the following docker containers

```
docker create \
--name=elasticsearch \
--restart=always \
--network=infrastructure_network \
--network-alias=elasticsearch \
-e TZ=Etc/UTC \
-e discovery.type=single-node \
-e "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms6g -Xmx6g" \
-e ELASTIC_PASSWORD="foobar" \
-p 9200:9200 \
-p 9300:9300 \
-v elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch \
elasticsearch:8.0.0

docker create \
--name=logstash \
--restart=always \
--network=infrastructure_network \
--network-alias=logstash \
-e TZ=Etc/UTC \
-p 5040:5040 \
-p 8514:8514/udp \
-v logstash:/usr/share/logstash/ \
-v elasticsearch:/elastic/ \
logstash:8.0.0
```

The containers start perfectly fine, but.. when I set the logstash output as follows:

```
input 
{
  tcp 
  {
    port => 8514
    type => syslog
  }
}

filter 
{
  if [type] == "syslog" 
  {
    grok 
    {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    date 
    {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss.SSS", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
      timezone => "UTC"
    }
  }
}

output 
{
    elasticsearch 
    {
        hosts => ['https://elasticsearch:9200']
        cacert => '/elastic/config/certs/http_ca.crt'
        ssl_certificate_verification => false
        user => "elastic"
        password => "foobar"
        index => "syslog"
        ilm_enabled => false
    }

    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I get the following error in the logstash logs...

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

[2022-03-02T03:27:04,496][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"https://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [https://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ClientProtocolException] PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"}

[2022-03-02T03:27:08,344][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Waiting for connectivity to Elasticsearch cluster, retrying in 16s

I'm assuming that I'm using the wrong cert maybe? It's the cert that is created when the elascticsearch container is spun up, what SHOULD I be using ??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file you point to in `cacert` contains the full chain of the certificate used on the elastic side (we've had it work with root first and then any intermediate CAs in order)

Answer (score -1):

add `ssl => true` to output elastic

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).